# Searching in a List<string> for all lines with a string less than 10 characters

Tags: c#, linq

I have a file with a 5 columns (tab delimited) record per line.
I have a public class where I created public string for each column.
Using LINQ to find all lines where the fifth column has a string less than 10 characters.

```
    class VogueRec
    {
        public string DOMAIN { get; set; }//0
        public string CLASSNAME { get; set; } //1
        public string CLASS { get; set; }//2
        public string KEYNAME { get; set; }//3
        public string KEY { get; set; }//4
    }
```

What is the best way to have the result of a query populate a new List from a FindAll search of List1.KEY lenght of string is < 10 then write to a new List.

```
            var lsCorrel = new List<VogueRec>();

        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fs))
        {
            while ((sData = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                if ((sData.IndexOf("\t")) == -1)
                    sData = sr.ReadLine();//jump over the code page in an correl export.//ignore line 1.        
                else
                {
                    #region READ USER
                    aSplit = sData.Split('\t');
                    while (aSplit[1] == "USER")
                    {
                        if (aSplit[3] != "CITY")
                        {
                            if (aSplit[3].IndexOf("CIT") == 0 || aSplit[3].IndexOf("VOICE") == 0)
                            {
                                lsCorrel.Add(new VogueRec()
                                {
                                    DOMAIN = aSplit[0],
                                    CLASS = aSplit[2],
                                    KEYNAME = aSplit[3],
                                    KEY = aSplit[4].Substring(Math.Max(0, aSplit[4].Length - 5))
                                });
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                    #endregion
                }
            }
        }
        var result = lsCorrel.Where(v => v.KEY.Length < 10);
```

Comment: Please post what you tried so we may best assist you here.

Comment: `list.Where(v => v.KEY.Length < 10)` maybe? What do you have so far?

Comment: this did not work. "var result = lsCorrel.Where(v => v.KEY.Length < 10);" returns nothing. but in debug "result.KEY" does have string with less than 10 characters.

Comment: I don't have much I tried as I don't know how to achieve my goal. I tried Charlieface with no joy.

Comment: I need to apologize to you Charlieface your code works. I was not looking on my side of the code. I had all numbers being strip to 5 digits before I ran your code. Now that I removed my "KEY = aSplit[4].Substring...." I'm just seeing records that are < 10 characters. Thank you.

Comment: That `while... break;` has to be some of the weirdest code I've seen for a while. Why are you looping only to break on the first run? Just don't loop at all.

Answer (score 1):

list.Where(v => v.KEY.Length < 10) maybe? What do you have so far? –
Charlieface
5 hours ago
worked. This is the answer my case.

Answer (score 0):

You first read the data line by line and put the key value less than 10 in a list

column separator: Tab("\t")
Line separator: line

```
 public class TestReadFile
    {
        public List<VogueRec> Get()
        {
            string path = @"D:\f\1.txt";
            List<VogueRec> VogueRecs = new List<VogueRec>();
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path))
            {
                while (sr.Peek() >= 0)
                {
                    string str;
                    string[] strArray;
                    str = sr.ReadLine();

                    strArray = str.Split('\t');
                    
                    if (strArray[4].Length < 10)
                    {
                        VogueRecs.Add(new VogueRec() { 
                            DOMAIN = strArray[0], CLASSNAME = strArray[1], CLASS = strArray[2], KEYNAME = strArray[3], KEY = strArray[4] 
                        });

                    }

                }

            }
            return VogueRecs;
        }


    }
```

Use

```
TestReadFile testReadFile = new TestReadFile();
var _list= testReadFile.Get();
```

Example

> ```
> fdfsf sdsds   dddd    dddd    142425414251
> asas  ddd     ssss    ssss    14200
> asa   sss     dddd    222     ssss
> asa   sss    dd22d    sss    14501235647
> ```

Result

> ```
> asas  ddd     ssss    ssss    14200
> asa   sss     dddd    222     ssss
> ```